# Google Analytics events tracking is way not accurate

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

To track submissions of a form we're using the google analytics events mechanism. The problem is that about 30% of submissions do not show on the google analytics event reports.

Here is our tracking code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;         i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-834692-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'GTM-T4KHK5P');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Here is code firing events:

```
try { 
    ga('send', 'event', 'quote', 'place', ga_label, 68, {hitCallback: EnableRequestSubmittedDialog, transport: 'beacon'}  ); 
}catch(e){
    $("#google-analytics-alert").show();
}

setTimeout(EnableRequestSubmittedDialog, 1500);
```

The above code is executed when data is successfully sent to server using ajax. The function EnableRequestSubmittedDialog just enables buttons on the  confirmation message so user can close the page. I also added code firing a debug event before the ajax call and transmitted a google analytics success flag to the server and saw that the ga( 'send', 'event', ... ) code was always executed successfully yet 30% of events did not appear in google analytics:

```
var ga_status = 'Failed.';
try { 
    if( ga.q ) //Google analytics not loaded for some reason
        ga_status = 'Google analytics seems blocked.';
else {
    ga('send', 'event', 'button-click', 'get-quote', ga_label, 1, {transport: 'beacon'}); //Post to google analytics each click to debug
    ga_status = 'Seems success.  label: ' + ga_label + '. transport: beacon';

formData.push({name: 'google-analytics', value: ga_status});
```

I've also found out that when a user submits the form several times, either all the events or no events appear in google analytics. I checked all the google analytics filters and they looked OK to me.

Is that normal that the Google Analytics events accuracy is 30% off? What else can be done to understand where the problem is?

The form URL is: https://www.emachineshop.com/quote/

Thank you in adance.

Comment: perhaps this is due to a privacy setting in the end users browser (or an add-on)

Comment: @Jaromanda , I'm about to think so, but hard to believe that so many users installed add-ons disabling google analytics tracking.

Comment: It's not so hard to believe really. Privacy is very important.